# gensim fails to install with the legacy-install-failure

Tags: c++, centos, gensim, centos8

I am trying to install gensim.

For this I ran the command

`pip install git+https://github.com/witiko/gensim.git@feature/bm25`.

But it does not install and fails with the following error message:

```
      building 'gensim.models.nmf_pgd' extension
      gcc -pthread -B /XXXX/envs/codex-env/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /XXXX/envs/codex-env/include -I/XXXX/envs/codex-env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /XXXX/envs/codex-env/include -fPIC -I/XXXX/codex-env/include/python3.9 -I/XXXX/envs/codex-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c gensim/models/nmf_pgd.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gensim/models/nmf_pgd.o
      gcc -pthread -B /XXXX/envs/codex-env/compiler_compat -shared -Wl,-rpath,/XXXX/envs/codex-env/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/XXXX/envs/codex-env/lib -L/XXXX/envs/codex-env/lib -L/XXXX/envs/codex-env/lib -Wl,-rpath,/XXXX/envs/codex-env/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/XXXX/envs/codex-env/lib -L/XXXX/envs/codex-env/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gensim/models/nmf_pgd.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gensim/models/nmf_pgd.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
      building 'gensim.similarities.fastss' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gensim/similarities
      gcc -pthread -B /XXXX/envs/codex-env/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /XXXX/envs/codex-env/include -I/XXXX/envs/codex-env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /XXXX/envs/codex-env/include -fPIC -I/XXXX/envs/codex-env/include/python3.9 -I/XXXX/envs/codex-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c gensim/similarities/fastss.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/gensim/similarities/fastss.o
      gensim/similarities/fastss.c: In function ‘ceditdist’:
      gensim/similarities/fastss.c:725:9: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
               for (WIDTH tmpi = 0; tmpi <= len_s1; tmpi++) row2[tmpi] = tmpi;
               ^
      gensim/similarities/fastss.c:725:9: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
      gensim/similarities/fastss.c:727:9: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
               for (WIDTH i2 = 0; i2 < len_s2; i2++) {
               ^
      gensim/similarities/fastss.c:738:13: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
                   for (WIDTH i1 = 0; i1 < len_s1; i1++) {
                   ^
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> gensim
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your local C compiler is objecting to some of the syntax in Gensim's (Cython-generated) `.c` code.

Your error output suggests a possible solution via an extra option to the compiler:

```
gensim/similarities/fastss.c:725:9: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

You *might* be able to add this flag via the environment variable `CFLAGS`, such as by setting it before your install command:

```
% CFLAGS="-std=c99" pip install git+https://github.com/witiko/gensim.git@feature/bm25
```

You *may* get a similar error related to some of Gensim's C++ files as well; if the error output includes a similar option-suggestion, you might need to supply it via the `CPPFLAGS` environment variable.

If that doesn't work, you could also edit such extra `gcc` options into Gensim's `setup.py` file. In such a case, get the `git` repository 1st, then locally-edit the `setup.py` file around the relevant `extra_args` lines in the `make_c_ext()` and `make_cpp_ext()` functions, then do a `pip install` specifying the changed-directory as the source.